# How to change GitHub PR to draft when no switch option is available?

Tags: github, pull-request

How can I change my GitHub PR to draft when the option is not available on the reviewer's tab?

I've seen some answers relating to the button that's available under the reviewer's tab, but mine doesn't show (as shown in the screenshot below)
[image: Screenshot of the reviewers tab]

I've tried finding the `switch to draft` button under the reviewer's tab, but it does not show up on my PR.